# Append text to element value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I multiply the integer value of 3 textboxes and display the result in a 4th textbox.

Before the value is displayed I want to check if the value contains any decimals, like 99.95. If it doesn't then the script shall append .00 to the value (99.00).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("input:text").each(function(){ 
        $(this).blur(function () { 
            var txt1 = $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').val();
            var txt2 = $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').val();
            var txt3 = $('#<%=TextBox3.ClientID %>').val();
            var txt4 = $('#<%=TextBox4.ClientID %>'); // To display the value.
            var value = parseFloat(txt1) + parseFloat(txt2) + parseFloat(txt3);
            txt4.val(value);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried various ways like:

```
if($(value).has('.').length === 0){ value.append('.00'); }
$(value).not('.').append('.00');
```

etc.

None of which has worked so far. I have tried any if-statement I can think of available with jQuery.

Comment: The reason why it does not work is you are using jQuery for something that it is not designed to do. jQuery works on DOM elements, not on strings. E.g. the description of `has` is: *Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.* So I suggest to read the documentation of functions before you use them ;)

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't match up with what you're saying you want to achieve. You said you're multiplying integers, but your sample code is adding floating point numbers. If you were indeed working with integers, the check you want to do becomes obsolete (multiplying three integers together will always result in another integer, so no decimal part).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
txt4.val(value.toFixed(2));
```

Little shorter, less headache.

- Document on [formatting numbers in javascript](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html)
- May also want to look in to [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) ([dev.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)) or [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) ([dev.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)) for your input fields

Comment: Prepending `mdc` to Google searches helps in finding documentation on MDC ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html)

JavaScript built-in methods toFixed and toPrecision